# converting tiff files to jpg from php

Tags: php, perl, imagemagick, exec

I am trying to convert a folder of tif files to jpeg so they can be displayed on my website.  my current approach is not working. i wrote a perl script with

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

opendir(DIR, $ARGV[0]);
@files = readdir(DIR);
closedir(DIR);

foreach $file (@files){
 if($file =~ /(.*?)\.tif/){
  print "converting $file\n";
  `convert -auto-level  -depth 12 -type grayscale $ARGV[0]$file $ARGV[1]$1.jpg`;
 }
}
```

But this never enters the for loop because the opendir fails. The folder does exist.

i am calling this by exec("perl test.pl arg1 arg2"); in php

Is this how i should be doing this because it isn't working?

Also i gave pretty much everything that needs to be accessed or written to chmod 777

thanks

Comment: Are you using relative or absolute paths? Does convert command work correctly if you call it from shell? You could easily rewrite the same code in php

Comment: Always test the result of open :
opendir(DIR, $ARGV[0]) or die "can't open '$ARGV[0]' : $!";

Comment: @Ivan the perl script works correctly when called from shell
@Pekka do you mean the full path? of what?
@M42 as stated in my question, opendir fails, i will add the die

Comment: Why in the world are you calling a Perl script from PHP whose sole job is to shell out to `convert`? Why not do this all within the original PHP script?

Comment: Well there are more complex perl tasks i would like to do at some point, if i can't get this to work, i won't be able to get those to work either. I really want to know why this doesn't work

Comment: @Ivan i am using relative paths

Comment: Try with absolute path. You're PHP script is probably run from some other executing directory, from which your relative path is not valid.. you can check this by calling getcwd()

Comment: i changed it to use absolute just to be safe, cwd was in the correct place though

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, you should *always* have these two lines in every script and module:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

These lines will give you many errors and clues that will tell you what you're missing.

Second, you need to check the return value of the `opendir` command, as it does return an error if it failed to open the directory (for example if it didn't exist).  The `$!` variable contains the most recent error message.  If you print the exact filename in the error message that you tried to open, you can see if your file specification is incorrect:

```
opendir (my $dir, $ARGV[0]) or die "Cannot open $ARGV[0]: $!";
my @files = readdir($dir);
closedir($dir);
```

If your directory specification is relative, and you are in the wrong directory, you can change directories with [chdir](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chdir.html).

The specifications for the opendir command are in [perldoc -f opendir](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/opendir.html).  You can read about special variables in [perldoc perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html).